# Asp.Net Website with Angular 4 - where is my Angular site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, angular

I am sure this is simple, but I am very new to Angular - so bear with me.

- In Visual Studio 2017, I created a new Blank Asp.Net Web Application (not Core)
- In that directory, I made a new Angular 4 site with the simple command `ng new admin`
- If I run `ng serve` everything works just fine
- If I debug (F5) my index.html shows up fine, but where is my angular site?! If I remove my index.php, I get nothing.  I have tried ~/app ~/admin, etc to no avail.  ***How do I find where this is running?!***

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using Angular-CLI. When you run `ng serve` it uses [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx) which holds all relevant files in memory for the speedy access. That's why you don't see any output on your local disk.

If you run `ng build` you will see `dist` folder with all the relevant files.

Comment: Running now! Do I just navigate to that folder then?

Comment: yes, it's a fully built website. It should have `index.html` and you can use any webserver to serve files from that folder

Comment: strange - I just get a blank html page served, not what was seen when I ran 'ng serve'

Comment: Awesome! Must have just been cached - pulling open the console fixed it all!